# How to include file assets to be used by your own package in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, assets

I have a package where I'm trying to load a string from my rootBundle. This file is to be used within the package itself only as part of internal configuration. I cant see where i'm going wrong.

This is my folder structure:

```
my-package
  --> lib
  --> pubspec.yaml
  --> assets/file.js
```

This is the content of my pubspec.yaml

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/file.js
```

This is how i'm calling it

```
String js = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/file.js');
```

I keep on getting unable to load asset

```
Unable to load asset: assets/file.js
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

had the same problem but solved it by doing this:

In your package's .yaml file, add this line to import the file/asset

```
assets:
- packages/<Package name>/assets/<File name>
```

Replace the `<Package name>` with the name of your package, and `<File name>` with the name of said file/asset.

Then place the file/asset in a folder under your lib directory of your package. The structure should look something like this:

```
my_package
--> lib
    --> assets
        file.js
```

*Make sure to add any additional folders to the reference if necessary.*

When referencing the file/asset in your app or package, use the same reference as in you .yaml file:

```
String js = await rootBundle.loadString('packages/<Package name>/assets/file.js');
```

For example, here I'm getting a .js file.

Comment: Thank you! This just solved an age old issue.  O i don’t have to duplicate plugin assets. I cant believe this took so long to get answered